# Disable automatic expansion of folder/parent when dragging objects into?

Tags: unity

I'm organizing a large scene.  I have a few subfolders like Trees, Flowers, etc.  When I drag a tree into the Trees folder, it expands the folder and scrolls to the bottom (where it added them).  Is there *any* way to disable this behavior?  I immediately have to scroll back up and collapse it so I can see the structure again.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but after dragging if I hit <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd> it collapses the folder.  Nice workaround.

Comment: This does not work if you drag multiple objects.  You have to first select a single object before cursor keys will work.